# Adjust div height dynamically based on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know there's a pretty simple way of doing this, but I can't seem to find anything in my searches.

I've found lots of examples of getting to a certain scroll location on the page and then animating a div to a different size, however I want to adjust a div's max height depending on the scroll location. Initially i'd like the div max-height to be about 150px, and then as you scroll from around 200px down the page to 400px down the page, I want the max-height of the div to decrease to 75px. Then obviously as you scroll back up, it gets larger.

I can't provide an example of what I've tried already, as I'm yet to attempt it as I have no idea on where to start.

**Note:** The size should gradually adjust with the scroll position.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem, but when I did I came out with this :D

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop < 200){
    maxHeight = 150;
  }else if(scrollTop > 400){
    maxHeight = 75;
  }else{
    maxHeight = 150 - 75 * (((scrollTop-200) * 100)/200)/100;
  }
  $('#thediv').stop().animate({'max-height': maxHeight+"px"}, 500);
})
```

Here you have a sample : https://jsfiddle.net/keccs4na/

Comment: I've marked this as answered, although i've changed the animation length to 1 so it's near enough instant. https://jsfiddle.net/x5a3hyyz/2/

Comment: would you be able to explain the maths behind it? I can't seem to understand how it works?

Comment: i've updated the example with no animate and simplified the math. The math calculates the ratio of scroll between 200 and 400 and applies to 75. Ex: If scrollTop is 245, the ratio will be (245-200) / 200 => 45 /200 = 0.225. After that we apply the ratio to 75 : 75 * 0.225 = 16.875.This means that the div will be with 16.875 smaller.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop >= 200 && scrollTop <= 400) {
        $('#divID').stop().animate({height: "75px"}, 250);
    } else {
        $('#divID').stop().animate({height: "150px"}, 250);   
    }
});
```

**Note:** You'll want to use CSS to initially set the height to `150px`.

Comment: This doesn't gradually adjust it. I've seen examples of this but I don't like the effect of getting to a set point and then animating. Ideally I want it to adjust as you scroll. So if you scroll only half way between the 2 points, it only adjusts the height half way between the minimum and maximum sizes. See here for an example of what I'd like to try and do http://www.kriesi.at/themes/enfold/

Comment: I've approved your edit, sorry it was confusing however I thought this line explained it "I've found lots of examples of getting to a certain scroll location on the page and then animating a div to a different size, however I want to adjust a div's max height depending on the scroll location.". Apologies again.

Comment: Haha indeed it does. I think the note will just provide further clarification as the two answers were based on the same logic. You're going to need to do some sort of mathematical function to calculate the scroll position with the max size for that position. Still looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var v = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (v > 200) {
        $('#id-of-div').css({"height": "75px","max-height":"75px"});
    }
    else {
        $('#id-of-div').css({"height": "150px","max-height":"150px"});
    }
});
```

EDIT:

```
   $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var v = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (v > 200) {
            $('#id-of-div').animate({"height": "75px","max-height":"75px"},500);
        }
        else {
            $('#id-of-div').animate({"height": "150px","max-height":"150px"},500);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This seems to just jump from one size to the other rather than easing between them.

Comment: @BN83 Yes,i have added an edit,which should make it a smoother effect.