# Change the height of div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the height of `div` when I scroll

```css
#H {
  position: fixed;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<div style="height:2000px; position:relative">
  <div id="H"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onscroll = function() {
    myFunction()
  };

  function myFunction() {
    VAR X = document.getElementById("H");
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
      X.css("height": "100px");
    } else {
      X.css("height": "200px");
    }
  }
</script>
```

But the code is not working. In the above code I tried to change the height of the `div` with `id="H"` on scroll from 200, that I have mentioned in the `CSS` to 100, but the `JS` is not running.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005636/adjust-div-height-dynamically-based-on-scroll

Comment: window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()}();

Comment: also correct you code it's 'var' in Javascript and not VAR.. Mind the case sensitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problem in JavaScript.

Change it to like:

```
<script>
 window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    var X=document.getElementById("H");
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
        X.style.height = "1000px";
    } 
    else {
       X.style.height = "200px";
        }
    }

</script>
```

`VAR X` should be `var X`

And

`X.css("height":"1000px");` change style like `X.style.height = "1000px";`

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whmemops/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

there are a few javascript errors in your code.

- VAR X=document...
  "var" has to be lower case, not upper case.
- X.css(...)
  "css" is not a function. Use X.style.height instead.

Generally look into how to debug javascript code. A good browser is your friend with this (e.g. Firefox or Chrome). Use console.log("foo"); to print a message or a variable to the browsers console to see what happens in your code. You can also use step by step debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the JavaScript console in your browser, you can see that document.getElementById("H").css is not a function.

Instead use for example document.getElementById("H").style.height = "300px";

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not directly accessible in JavaScript unless you use `getComputedStyle` API, however the class can be accessed using `element.className` and changed as long as you have the relevant `class` already created.

`element.style.property` is how you change inline styles. There is a big difference in both, in that one is part of the DOM structure while the other is connected to the DOM via a `class` name and the `stylesheet`.

Specific to you question:

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dr65pmw/1/)

`window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};` is simply `window.onscroll = myFunction` it is the same and more idiomatic.