# Dynamically change height of div using onscroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jquery to change the height of a div across a bottom and top nav as on this **[codepen](https://codepen.io/RichardThompson/pen/NXaZoV)**.

**The jquery is this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var img = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      // downscroll code
      console.log('downward')
      img = img + 1;
      $('.img').height(img);
    } else if (st < lastScrollTop) {
      // upscroll code
      console.log('upward')
      img = img - 1;
      $('.img').height(img);
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;

  }).scroll();
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Below is the html for the jquery:

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <nav>
    <div class='topnav'>
      <div class='img'>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='bottomnav'>
      
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class='main'>
    I am main content 
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the console.logs scrolling down doesn't match the console.logs scrolling upwards. So the polygon div spanning both navs doesn't end up where it's supposed to. Please see the image below for console.logs:

[image]

I am trying to make the top nav disappear as you scroll the grey nav becomes fixed and the polygon shaped div becomes the size of the grey nav component. The idea is to get a similar effect like the one on fantasy premier leagues website.

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more details please ask and ill provide clarification.

Comment: I added `height` to your snippet, now it respond but i think need add some `html` to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling upwards and downwards do not always happen in increments of 1, hence the mismatch. If you scroll upwards slowly, its count would exceed downwards scroll. Instead what you need to do is, determine the breakpoints where you want the changes to happen. So for e.g. you want the top navbar to disappear on scroll. The top navbar has height of 50, so when your scrollTop exceeds 50, make grey bar position fixed and at the top. Check this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RxjoeG

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var img = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st >= 50) {
      $('.bottomnav').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':0});
    } else {
      $('.bottomnav').css({'position':'initial'});
    }
  }).scroll();
})
```

Comment: I have upvoted because you basically gave me the answer! i changed the +1 and -1 to the difference between the current scrolltop to the previous scrolltop, thereby changing the size of the div to the amount which was scrolled. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wonderful! Glad that my answer helped you!

Comment: Can you maybe help me with this problem, you did answer my question. But I'm trying to get the same effect on this website https://fantasy.premierleague.com/, i cant seem to replicate it. Can you help?

Comment: Hi, sorry for seeing this comment late. I see that you already implemented it on your site. Do you still need help?

Comment: I am stilling having issues with the math in the codepen. I cant seem to figure it out to get it to work.

Comment: I am stilling having issues with the math in the codepen. I cant seem to figure it out to get it to work. This is the math i decided to go for, there is a fiddle with it working on this post:Adjust div height dynamically based on scroll: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005636/adjust-div-height-dynamically-based-on-scroll. But i need it to work between 0px and 50px not 200px to 400px.

Comment: Can you the check the codepen I have posted above? The properties changes  between 0 and 50px like you want. Let me know what exactly is needed so I make appropriate changes to the codepen

Comment: Yes, check the codepen above. Just focus on the concept and you can adapt it to do what you want

Comment: I can only see the codepen relating to using position fixed on the grey nav component. Not dynamically changing the height of the polygon shape?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with polygon shape?