# Material UI Drawer responsive height?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

Im trying to get this material-ui persistent side drawer's height to be responsive to the rest of the site.

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-wescoff-16ogs

Basically I want it to behave similar to the 'purple' section, where it gets "squished down" by the 'blue' bar when the page is scrolled up but otherwise behaves the same as it does now.

I don't know if its the best solution, but the only way I can think it would work - but cant actually write ([something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31007328/12104850)) - is for the drawer to have a variable height that changes with the scroll position... but that still seems like overkill? Surely it can be done with CSS/JSS alone?

Thanks, any help much appreciated