# How to change the height of a div dynamically based on the scroll position in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to dynamically change the height of a div based on the scroll position using javascript.
Now the height of div does change but I can't see it.Here's my code:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('div').style.height = window.scrollY + 'px'
})
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    height:3000px;
}

div{
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Scroll Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi drunken, I believe this thread may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005636/adjust-div-height-dynamically-based-on-scroll

This article may also be useful: https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    min-height:3000px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#test {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('#test').style.minHeight = window.scrollY + 'px';
})
```

You can checkout the working example here:
https://jsbin.com/kajudisaga/edit?html,css,js

Comment: your code works but what's wrong with my code and why did you add position sticky to the div?

Comment: I added some other content under the div and now the document won't stop scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I would just add: window.scrollY*2

```
document.querySelector('div').style.height = window.scrollY + window.scrollY*2 + 'px'
```

Comment: the height won't stop increasing

Comment: - use some if statements to stop at a height you want.
- It will increase and decrease depends on the scrollY
- You can change the number 2 to smaller one to lower the speed but don't go under 1
- When you think about the logic behind what you're trying to achieve, I think you should think another way to do it

Comment: I replaced window.scrollY with window.scrollY*1.25 in my code and now it works